# counting the elements in datatable

Tags: anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgDvR.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbrcW.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InPXj.png)

i have been trying to count the no of elements in data table, but therehas been some mistake where the error shows "cant convert long to int". i am defining it to the parameter. can some one please help me with it. i changed the name of data table and used both the codes mentioned below yet no luck

CODE:

1)selectFrom(comp)
.groupBy(comp.components)
.uniqueResult(comp.components.count());```

2)selectFrom(comp)
.groupBy(comp.components.count());

Error : "Type mismatch : cannot convert from long to int"

Data Table : Name is "comp" and column "Components" have the names(string) of the components

Comment: Do share more screenshots. How to you "define it to a parameter"? The full error msg, and where it is triggered. Make it easy for us please :)

Comment: Thx. Have you tried a simple approach where you only have 2-3 dbase items and count those? Does that work? (I suspect you may have some faulty row). What if you do not map it to a param but call the code in a button using `traceln(selectFrom...)`

Comment: sorry for not attaching the pics in first place. i tried with 2-3 items yet i get the same error, but with using `traceln()´ there is something been written to console "com.anylogic.engine.database.Selectquery@........." i added a Screenshort of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually works fine, just retested for you with [this example model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gyvp0wrvw0xzcbp/Model38.zip?dl=0).

So 2 options:

1. You are using an old version of AnyLogic or some old Java or some OS specific weird thing (less likely)
2. You are loading "unclean" data. Likely, you load from an Excel file that has some formulas behind the cells you load. Always make sure to load 100% "clean" data, i.e. pure data, no formula.

Check if my example model works on your machine and if it does: solve for #2, i.e. fix your data

Comment: Thankyou Mr.benjamin now it works, its the excel work sheet with formulas created this problem.